# how to intercept ID when a DIV scrolls over

Tags: javascript

I have a DIV (fixed position) in an HTML page, everything works fine, but while scrolling the DIV scrolls over a photo with id="myid". I would like that when the DIV is above the photo a CSS class is added.

I don't know JavaScript and have no idea how to intercept the ID

here I found a clearer example, from Desktop, scrolling the page, a div appears on the left, continuing to scroll there is the photo of airplanes:

https://medium.com/war-is-boring/is-the-u-s-air-force-ready-for-a-new-light-attack-aircraft-79562bf64882

Comment: That's tricky. You need to watch both element's position when the scroll event is fired. Then, you need to compare those elements and find out if they overlap (by using the position and height of the elements).

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: here I found a clearer example: https://medium.com/war-is-boring/is-the-u-s-air-force-ready-for-a-new-light-attack-aircraft-79562bf64882

from Desktop, scrolling the page, a div appears on the left, continuing to scroll there is the photo of airplanes